# Does terminal have quickedit mode?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I like the quickedit mode in Windows cmd. It is convinient to copy and paste.

So I am searching a way to make it done in Ubuntu terminal.

Quickedit mode in Windows cmd:

1. make selection in terminal using the cursor
2. copy by right click selection
3. paste by right click

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is already something equivalent to this: by highlighting any text (not just in the terminal, but in almost any application), that text is put into the xclipboard. You can paste it by clicking the *middle* mouse button. If you're using a touchpad with no middle button, Ubuntu should allow you to click both buttons simultaneously to simulate a middle mouse click.

This is distinct from the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> clipboard you are probably used to.

Comment: Hi, I've got no middle mouse button (laptop). Any other way to quickedit?

Answer (score 5):

Like in text editor, you can make selection in terminal using the cursor. But to copy/paste from/to the terminal you'll have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you install guake terminal (sudo apt-get install guake). It's great for usage and has many pretty features. Try it.

Comment: Guake *is* awesome, but I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: damnit... went `sudo apt-get quake`.  Coding's gona have to wait now...